# Devise Invitable: user.invite! doesn't work in test environment

Tags: rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-invitable

I need to call `user.invite!` as part of my tests. This is using Devise invitable and so should both send an invitation to the user and also create an invitation token for them and save them to the database.

Unfortunately, in the test environment nothing happens and calling `user.invite!` simply returns `nil` and makes no changes to the user object.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I stubbed the `invite!` method so it didn't do anything.

As you were.

Comment: lol.. i didn't stubbed it, I was just looking for a way to have a non accepted invitation user lol.. but you got me lololololol